# Why is this Szudzik Elegant Pairing giving wrong result?

Tags: java, algorithm, function, math, equation

I'm pairing two numbers to form a unique number using elegant pairing. But when I pair two same numbers above 67108863 e.g "pair(67108864,67108864)" it gives me 4503599761588224. When I want to unpair it, it's going to give me (-1,67108865). I then tried to pair (-1,67108865), it gives me 4503599761588224 also. All other different numbers gives a unique number or same number under 67108864, I can pair and unpair them unless I pair the same number above 67108863; (67108864,67108864),(507108864,507108864), etc.

Is there an error in my code or I just found an issue with Szudzik Elegant Pairing Function?

```
/**
 *
 * @author HiltherJoe
 */
public class ElegantP {
    public static long pair(long x, long y) {
        return x >= y ? x * x + x + y : y * y + x;
    }
    public static long[] unpair(long z) {
        long b = (long) Math.sqrt(z);
        long a = z - b * b;
        return a < b ? new long[]{a, b} : new long[]{b, a - b};
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 67108864;
        long pairedNumber = pair(i, i);
        long[] unpair = unpair(pairedNumber);
        System.out.println("Paired Number is    " + pairedNumber);
        System.out.println("First unpaired Number is    " + unpair[0]+"    Second unpaired Number is    "+unpair[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's due to overflow. Long has a range value which you are breaching by taking square of a value.

Comment: @SMA I don't think it's an overflow issue, because larger numbers works and return back the original numbers. Try other different numbers that are bigger than 67108864, you will see that you will get the numbers back. Also, why would it work for 67108863 and not 67108864?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is using `Math.sqrt()` which does `double` calculation - the result is not exact enough. For `4503599761588224` (`pair(67108864,67108864)`), it is resulting in `67108865` instead of `67108864`.

Use `BigInteger.sqrt()` (or any other **exact** method) and it should work:

```java
long b = BigInteger.valueOf(z).sqrt().longValue();
long a = z - b * b;
```

<sub>for bigger number there is still the overflow risk as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035146/why-is-this-szudzik-elegant-pairing-giving-wrong-result/59035596#comment104313298_59035146) by SMA</sub>

Comment: That's true for overflow, incase of bigger numbers I just use BigInteger